# Rendered page missing DOCTYPE on POST

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, cdi, mojarra

I'm experiencing a weired behavoiour (at least in my eyes).

Somehow the DOCTYPE and html-tag are missing when I do a post from a template which has an include.

Let's say I do a GET on home1.xhtml that uses template1.xhtml which has widget.xhtml included. Now I do a POST on home2.xhtml. Now the resonse is missing the DOCTYPE and html-tag.

If I

- do a GET directly on home2.xhtml or
- replace the include in template1.xhtml with the contents of the include and do a POST

DOCTYPE and html-tag are in the response as expected.

home1.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="template1.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="content">

  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

template1.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" >
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  Called with GET
  <ui:include src="widget.xhtml" />
  <h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{homeBean2.show}" value="POST" />
  </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

wigdet.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" >
  <h:form id="someForm">
  </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

home2.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="template2.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="content">
    POST 1
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

template2.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" >
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    template 2
</h:body>
</html>
```

How can I get the DOCTYPE and html-tag to show up in the rendered page?

Any hints what I'm missing here?

Jonny

Comment: What JSF impl/version exactly are you using? How exactly is PrimeFaces related to this? Does the problem disappear when you remove PrimeFaces? Also how exactly is Tomcat6 related to this? Does the problem disappear if you use Tomcat7 or even another server like Glassfish? If they're completey unrelated, please remove the tagging and mention their exclusion of being the cause in the question.

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks for your comment.I will look into this and try to strip down my project further.First thing I'll do on monday.

Comment: Hi folks, unfortunately I hadn't had the time to strip down my project to narrow down the lib that is causing the trouble. But theres one thing: **After updating Mojarra from 2.1.9 to 2.1.10** I'm getting at least the `html-tag` again, but `DOCTYPE` is still missing.

Comment: Ok, I stripped down my project as far as possible removing primefaces, etc.. Mojarra causes this problem. Using MyFaces as the jsf-implementation works. Anybody got an idea where exactly to debug mojarra to nail this problem (bug?)?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem on a blank and minimal playground project. So it's likely an environmental misconfiguration.

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks for looking into this. I'll keep on stripping down further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug. please see http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2453

Comment: I have got the Netbeans project to reproduce the problem. Please let me know, if you need it.